# d3 - Append actions to existing listeners?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

For d3 behaviors, what is the best way to add additional actions in addition to default listeners?  For example, here's what I'm doing if I want to do something with `d3.behaviors.drag` on `dragstart`:

```
var drag = d3.behaviors.drag();
var originalDragstart = drag.on("dragstart");
drag.on("dragstart", function(d) {
  originalDragstart.call(this, d);
  // do other stuff
});
```

Comment: That's a bit dodgy coz you loose your `this` context.  I don't know if [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30843077/2670182) is helpful but it seems similar to what you are doing... it's really a question and answer rolled into one.

Comment: Edited to pass in the this context.

Answer (score 0):

You normally will be augmenting them, `on` takes a callback as the 2nd parameter where you can define custom logic. So you may for example take something like `drag` and do:

```
drag.on("drag", function(d) { 
   // Move something
   d3.select(this)
     .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
     .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });
});
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by augmenting them here, because the d3 docs (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#on) explicitly state that existing listeners will be removed, so if the `"drag"` event listener already has a listener, it won't get called in your code.

Comment: @hgcrpd Sorry, I mean if you have custom logic you normally put it within the callback, which is combining it with the underlying internal logic of `drag` within `d3`.